# Curl POST request using pycurl

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

someone can me explain how can i use curl request below in pycurl library:

`curl -X POST --user 'username:password' url`

Thanks.

Comment: don't bother use python requests instead. That's the most pythonic library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be answering your question with a suggestion, but without knowing your reasons for using PyCurl, I'm going to suggest you use the 'requests' module.

PyCurl is useful for very high network-intensive tasks, but otherwise, the 'requests' module is vastly easier and less painful to use.

To do as you ask with requests, the following works:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.yoururl.here'

requests.post('url', auth=('username', 'password'))
```

Or, to be a little safer and better informed, use:

```
import requests

try:
    response = requests.post('url', auth=('username', 'password'))
    print('Response HTTP Status Code: {status_code}'.format(
        status_code=response.status_code
        )
    )
    print('Response HTTP Response Body: {content}'.format(
        content=response.content
        )
    )
except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
    print( 'HTTP Request failed', response.content )
```

Assuming your POST works, the above isn't strictly necessary, nor is it particular to using 'requests', but it will let you know how things went with your request went. It's nothing but a try: except: approach to the same thing, with some print() statements to report back how everything worked out. :)

And assuming you have data to post, 'requests' makes that simple as well. See the following for more comprehensive information:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

If you are constrained to using PyCurl, though, have you looked at their Quickstart page? The last couple or three sections, in particular, may help:

http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: Thanks. Your solution helps to understand the problem. It works for me now.

Comment: Glad I could help. All the best.

Comment: You really understood what i need. Big thx.

Comment: You bet! Feel free to ask me more. I'm dealing with this stuff a lot lately, and can always use upvotes answers. :D Have a wonderful holiday.

Comment: Please consider not using requests. It is not thread-safe, and has memory leaks.